# Why get property works differently then function in Vue, it looks like I have to use function instead of getter for some unknown under the hood reason

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

This returns wrong values

```
    get scrollTop() {
        return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
    }
```

but this

```
    scrollTop() {
        return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
    }
```

works as expected, is this some hidden gem in Vue or typescript or its javascript thing ? 
I don't know how can I now rely on properties with more readable syntax when I somehow cannot explain why sometimes they don't work, leading to slow of my development, so it's more reliable to use function always. Can I expect more situations like this ?

```
<template>
    <div :style="computedStyle" class="tooltip">
        <div ref="tooltip-background" v-html="svg" class="tooltip-background"/>
        <div class="tooltip-content">
            <div v-if="nearestItem" class="tooltip-content-values">
                <span class="">{{getChartTitle(nearestItem)}}: </span>
                <span class="tooltip-content-values-value">{{nearestItem.value}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip-content-date">{{date}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
    .tooltip {
        pointer-events: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
    }

    .tooltip-background {
        width: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1
    }

    .tooltip-content {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        margin-left: 25px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    .tooltip-content-values {
        margin-top: 2px;
        font-family: Work Sans, sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
        color: #666666;
    }

    .tooltip-content-values-value {
        font-family: Work Sans, sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
        color: #111111;
    }

    .tooltip-content-date {
        margin-top: 3px;
        font-family: Work Sans, sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 24px;
        color: #666666;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
</style>

<script lang="ts">
    import {Component, Vue} from "vue-property-decorator"
    import {BMChartData, BMChartTooltipType, ChartTooltipModel} from "@/components/charts/ChartTypes";
    import Chart, {ChartTooltipItem} from "chart.js";
    import {is, log, stringify} from "@/extensions/CSLang";
    import {CSPoint} from "@/extensions/CSPoint";

    @Component
    export default class BMChartTooltip extends Vue implements BMChartTooltipType {

        chart: Vue | null = null
        model: ChartTooltipModel | null = null
        data: BMChartData | null = null
        lastHover: MouseEvent | null = null
        svg = require(`@/assets/img/icons/tooltip-background.svg`)
        date: String = "12.Jul, Tuesday, 19:10"
        nearestItem: ChartTooltipItem | null = null

        get tooltipBackground() {
            return this.$refs["tooltip-background"] as HTMLDivElement
        }

        get computedStyle() {
            return {
                left: this.tooltipLeft,
                top: this.tooltipTop,
                visibility: this.nearestItem ? "visible" : "hidden"
            }
        }

        get tooltipLeft() {
            if (this.nearestItem) return (this.scrollLeft() + this.chartRect().left + this.nearestItem.x! + 10) + "px"
            return `0px`
        }

        get tooltipTop() {
            if (this.nearestItem) return (this.scrollTop() + this.chartRect().top + this.nearestItem.y! - 42) + "px"
            return `0px`
        }

        scrollLeft() { //Cannot be getter because then returns wrong value !!!
            return window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft
        }

        scrollTop() { //Cannot be getter because then returns wrong value !!!
            return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
        }

        chartRect() {
            return this.chart!.$el.getBoundingClientRect()
        }

        get items(): ChartTooltipItem[] {
            let items = Array<ChartTooltipItem>()
            if (this.model && this.model.dataPoints)
                for (let item of this.model.dataPoints)
                    if (item.x == this.model.caretX) items.push(item)
            return items
        }

        borderColor(value: string) {
            for (let element of this.tooltipBackground.children[0].getElementsByTagName("path"))
                element.setAttribute("fill", value)
        }

        onUpdate(chart: Vue, model: ChartTooltipModel, data: BMChartData): void {
            if (model && model.dataPoints && model.dataPoints!.length > 0) {
                this.chart = chart
                this.model = model
                this.data = data
                this.updateNearestItem()
            }
        }

        onHover(event: MouseEvent, activeElements: Array<{}>) {
            this.lastHover = event
            this.updateNearestItem()
            if (this.nearestItem) {
                let lineColor = this.data!.charts[this.nearestItem.datasetIndex!].lineColor
                this.borderColor(lineColor)
                this.date = this.nearestItem.label ? this.nearestItem.label : ""
            }
        }

        updateNearestItem() {
            let nearestDistance = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
            this.nearestItem = null
            for (let item of this.items) {
                let distance = new CSPoint(item.x! + this.chartRect().left, item.y! + this.chartRect().top)
                    .distance(CSPoint.fromEvent(this.lastHover!))
                if (distance < nearestDistance) {
                    nearestDistance = distance
                    this.nearestItem = item
                }
            }
        }

        getChartTitle(item: ChartTooltipItem): string {
            return this.data ? this.data.charts[item.datasetIndex!].title : ""
        }
    }

</script>
```

As you can see three methods has to be defined as functions not properties scrollLeft scrollTop and chartRect otherwise I get wrong values... It looks like they are called from some different context somehow so and all of the get values from document dom elements so maybe there is clue of this behavior.

Comment: It'll be Vue.js, not TypeScript or JavaScript. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). Stack Snippets support Vue.js.

Comment: Can you show us some more code context? like the class under which `scrollTop` method is defined?

Comment: And thanks to guys wanting to close it as always, interesting hard to solve questions has to be closed, because the most wise ones cannot digest it. Maybe I will get time for making fiddle but I work on more projects and I need to survive so no time for that right now.